# Почему файлы .json нельзя оставлять пустыми?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Начал изучать модуль 'json' в Python и во время использования возник такой вопрос: Почему если я создал файл .json и он пустой, при попытке его открыть вылазит следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arsen/PycharmProjects/Hello_World/Learning_Python/Chapter 10/10-13.py", line 30, in <module>
    greet_user()
  File "C:/Users/arsen/PycharmProjects/Hello_World/Learning_Python/Chapter 10/10-13.py", line 21, in greet_user
    username = get_stored_username()
  File "C:/Users/arsen/PycharmProjects/Hello_World/Learning_Python/Chapter 10/10-13.py", line 9, in get_stored_username
    username = json.load(file)
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Не понимаю почему файл нельзя оставлять пустым?

Исходник:

```
import json

filename = 'username.json'


  def get_stored_username():
    try:
     with open(filename) as file:
        username = json.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
      return None
    else:
      answer = input("Your name is " + username + '? (+ or -)')
      if answer == '+':
        return "Welcome back "+username+"!"
      else:
        return None


  def greet_user():
    username = get_stored_username()
    if username:
       print(username)
    else:
       username = input('Enter your name ')
       with open(filename, 'a') as file:
         json.dump(username, file)


 greet_user()
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить туда две скобки `{}`

Comment: @suit , нельзя, типовая ошибка

Comment: А какая кодировка? Попробуйте без BOM

Comment: Отвечая на вопрос из заголовка — потому что пустота не является корректным json-элементом

Answer (score 2):

> Почему файлы .json нельзя оставлять пустыми?

Как уже написал [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213) в комментарии к вопросу - потому что пустота не является корректным json-элементом.

Корректными будут файлы с таким содержимым:

- `null`
- `{}`
- `[]`

Если вам нужно чтобы пустые файлы корректно отрабатывались - считывайте файл сначала в строку, потом проверяйте что там вообще что-то есть. Также неплохо будет проверить, что в файле корректный json (для этого нужно отлавливать исключение `JSONDecodeError`) и что считана именно строка.

```
def get_stored_username():
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            # Читаем содержимое файла, обрезаем пробелы в начале и в конце
            # (тогда файл содержащий только пробелы или переносы строк
            #  будет эквивалентен пустому файлу)
            file_content = file.read().strip()

            # Проверяем, пустой ли файл
            if not file_content:
                return None

            # Декодируем json
            username = json.loads(file_content)

            # Проверяем, что считана именно строка:
            if not isinstance(username, str):
                return None
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    except json.JSONDecodeError:  # Некорректное содержимое файла
        return None
    else:
        answer = input("Your name is " + username + '? (+ or -)')
        if answer == '+':
            return "Welcome back "+username+"!"
        else:
            return None
```

---

Еще одно: в конце кода вы открываете файл в режиме дозаписи (`open(filename, 'a')`). Нужно учитывать, что если в корректный файл json дозаписать еще один json объект, то файл станет некорректным. Например:

- `[][]` - некорректно (несколько json элементов в одном json файле)
- `"user1""user2"` (`json.dump` не добавляет перенос строки) - некорректно

Даже если при записи в файл добавлять перенос строки, например:

```
"user1"
"user2"
```

- все равно такое содержимое будет некорректным json (несколько json элементов в одном файле).

Корректным будет такой файл:

```
["user1", "user2"]
```

Для добавления новых записей нужно сразу считывать данные как список, добавлять в список элементы, **полностью перезаписывать** старый файл новыми данными.

Answer (score 1):

записать в файл строку:

```
[]
```

должно быть корректно

Проверил на PHP

```php
php -r "var_dump(json_decode('[]'));"
```

получаем:

```php
array(0) {
}
```

Почему пустой файл не соответствует стандарту json? Формат требует начинать и заканчивать запись особым образом. Потому же, пустой файл не может отвечать стандартам XML, например, как ты его ни награждай расширением xml.

Comment: Опять таки, возникает типовая ошибка, сообщающая о том, что в файл можно записывать только строки

Comment: Вам же ясно написали, что нужно добавить СТРОКУ из двух скобок.

Comment: Как ваш ответ отвечает на поставленный вопрос "Почему файлы .json нельзя оставлять пустыми?" ?

Answer (score 0):

А всего-то надо проверять пустой файл или нет.
Я полагаю что в библиотеке не проверяется наличие в файле информации, поэтому парсинг начинается как есть, отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/442976)

Comment: В моем ответе содержится решение вопроса.